# Google Event API: Event updated, email notification not sent

Tags: python, python-requests, google-calendar-api

I want to update a Google Event via the API using the requests library in Python.

When I send the patch request, the event is updated, but no notification are sent although I set up the parameters as specified [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch#request).

my code:

```py
payload = {
  # ...
}

headers = {
  # ...
}

params = {"sendUpdates": "all"}

request_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/{google_event_id}"

response = requests.patch(
  url=request_url, headers=headers, json=payload, params=params
)
```

I also tried with the deprecated parameter `sendNotifications`, I tried putting the parameters in the the payload, write them manually as url parameters but it still doesn't work.
Am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried with update instead of patch? It should send notifications via email. [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#notifications)

Comment: @DaImTo Yes but same result...

Comment: Have you found a solution? If not can you update the question with more information? Have you tried using the Try this! section on the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some checks with "Try this" section I realized that the email notification was sent only if some key fields were modified (for example `summary` or `attendees`). I was trying by updating the `description` only which doesn't send a notification.

My above snippet works for updating key fields.